# Analytic expression for non-trivial commutators

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Motivated by a previous [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79296/6316), consider bosonic creation/anihilation operators $a, a^+$ such that $[a, a^+]=1$, and $N = a^+a$.

Is there an analytic expression for the following commutators:

$[e^{za}, e^{wN}]$  and $[e^{za^+}, e^{wN}]$

where $z$ and $w$ are complex (belong to $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Your expression for the total number of bosons in the system is wrong.  It is supposed to be the sum over all of these number operators (you should have accepted my edit).  Also, it is a triviality, but the creation operators are supposed to have daggers, not plus signs (also in my edit).

Comment: @MaxGraves Trimok is referring to a single copy of the $a,a^\dagger, N$ operator algebra; there is only one number operator.  Also, the plus sign notation is common.

Comment: @joshphysics does $a^{\dagger}a$ just check for a given many-body state in this notation?  I have not seen this written this way.

Comment: @MaxGraves See, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Ladder_operator_method

Comment: @joshphysics Ohhhh, my mistake.  I am used to seeing this as $\hat{n}$.  I am so used to seeing N as the total number of particles in a system that I couldn't see through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no unique representations, so we will assume that OP is mostly interested in normal-ordered expressions between the three operators $a^{\dagger}$, $a$ and $N:=a^{\dagger}a$. Here $[a,a^{\dagger}]=1$. The underlying identities are

$$ \tag{1} [a,N] ~=~a \qquad\text{and}\qquad [N,a^{\dagger}] ~=~a^{\dagger}, $$

which lead to

$$ \tag{2}  f(a)e^{zN}~=~ e^{zN} f(e^{z} a)\qquad\text{and}\qquad 
 e^{zN}f(a^{\dagger})~=~ f(e^{z} a^{\dagger})e^{zN}, $$

respectively. Here $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is a complex number, and $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is a sufficiently well-behaved function, e.g. an exponential function. So the sought-for commutators read in normal-order form

$$ 
\tag{3}  [f(a),e^{zN}]~=~ e^{zN} \{f(e^{z} a)-f(a)\},
$$

and

$$ 
\tag{4}  [e^{zN},f(a^{\dagger})]~=~  \{f(e^{z} a^{\dagger})-f(a^{\dagger})\}e^{zN},
$$

respectively. More generally, one has

$$ 
\tag{5} e^{zN}f(a^{\dagger},a)~=~ f(e^{z} a^{\dagger},e^{-z} a)e^{zN}, $$

with corresponding commutator

$$ 
\tag{6}  [e^{zN},f(a^{\dagger},a)]~=~  \{f(e^{z} a^{\dagger},e^{-z} a)-f(a^{\dagger},a)\}e^{zN}.
$$

Comment: My original question had to do with $e^{iHt/\hbar}e^{-ipa/\hbar}e^{-iHt/\hbar}$ for the harmonic oscillator, especially $T(t)$ the translation operator. Your equations are very useful, but does $T(t)$ mean anything physically? It's not an observable, but would displacement of the SHO wave function vary over time?

Comment: Great. I finally got the trick to demonstrate $2$ and $5$. This was obvious (applying the operators to any basis vector $|n\rangle$), but I shamely did not think to this...